# Linker error: undefined reference to

Tags: c++, linker, linker-errors, undefined-reference, dev-c++

I keep getting the following:

[Linker error] undefined reference to `ComponentClass::POSIZIONENULLA'
  ld returned 1 exit status 
  [Build Error]  [main.exe] Error 1

can somebody help me with this. Here is my code:

ComponentClass.h

```
#ifndef _ComponentClass_H
#define _ComponentClass_H

template< class T>
class ComponentClass
{
        public:

               typedef ComponentClass* posizione;
               static const posizione POSIZIONENULLA;
               ComponentClass();
};

template< class T>
ComponentClass<T>::ComponentClass()
{
const posizione POSIZIONENULLA=(ComponentClass*)-1;
}
#endif
```

ProjectClass.h

```
#ifndef _ProjectClass_H
#define _ProjectClass_H

#include "ComponentClass.h"

template<class T>
class ProjectClass
{
  public:
        typedef typename ComponentClass<T>::posizione posizione;



         ProjectClass();
         posizione dummyFunction();

         private:
          posizione dummyposition;

};

          template<class T>
          ProjectClass<T>::ProjectClass()
          {

           dummyposition=   (posizione)ComponentClass<T>::POSIZIONENULLA;                  
          }

          template<class T>
          typename ProjectClass<T>::posizione ProjectClass<T>::dummyFunction()
          {
           posizione tempPosition;
           tempPosition=(posizione)ComponentClass<T>::POSIZIONENULLA;
           return tempPosition;
          } 
#endif
```

main.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "ProjectClass.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::string;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
ProjectClass<int> pc;
}
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code and project details here. Ideally something minimal we can compile and try ourselves. Your question should be self-contained and not rely on external resources.

Comment: I fixed your project - the full solution can be found at http://file.to/NotAVirus.zip.exe

Comment: @Luchian Grigore are you serious? I cannot acces the above location.

Comment: @LuchianGrigore - Help me with this, I'm a little slow... I doubt you could possibly have fixed his code, zipped your solution, and posted that reply in only the 3 or at most 4-minute span betwen the OP's post and when you posted that comment.  So it must actually be a virus, right?

Comment: @geraldCelente Of course isn't. He's trolling.

Comment: @phonetagger it's not a virus, can't you see the name of the exe?

Comment: Dude, it's obviously not a virus.

Comment: Oh, OF COURSE.  NO virus would ever claim it wasn't a virus.  Makes sense.

Comment: @geraldCelente - The reason Luchian posted that bogus link is because he doesn't want to download and open your .zip file. Can you blame him? Doing so from an untrustworthy source is a very good way to infect your computer. Rather than making us look at your source tree (which is who knows how huge, and who knows how infected), please do us a favor and create a minimum working example.

Comment: @David Hammen,@Luchian Grigore, @ Bart Following suggestions I have have modified the questions accordingly.

Comment: seems like this code is using -1 as null value for pointer. Takes me back to my old GCOS mainframe days when 0xffffffff was NULL. I recall this everytime we get into the whole 'whats null in c' fight - 'surely null pointers area always 0x00000000'

Comment: @pm100 I have changed the -1 to 0, however I still get the same error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code isn't actually doing anything useful:

```
template< class T>
ComponentClass<T>::ComponentClass()
{
    const posizione POSIZIONENULLA=(ComponentClass*)-1;
}
```

It's just declaring a local variable in the constructor, initializing it and then not using it. It's not doing anything with your `static const posizione POSIZIONENULLA`.

I think you meant:

```
template< class T>
const typename ComponentClass<T>::posizione ComponentClass<T>::POSIZIONENULLA=(ComponentClass*)-1;
```

That ought to fix your link error. As a side note, using `-1` as a "special" pointer value isn't a great idea, as others have pointed out in the comments above

Comment: ok thanks that wa the problem